# VB scripts hangs on more rows in excel although I want single row data from excel

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have a scrip to sent mail from excel via outlook .
Here i select a cell and copy it as html and sent to outlook .

but in hangs in method `Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)` at line  `RangetoHTML = ts.readall`   when no. of row are upto 70 .

Can someone help.

```
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a fixed range if you want
    'Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").Range("D4:D12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "xxxxx@xxxxx.com"
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Report" & Format(Now, "dd-MM-yyyy")
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Display   'or use .Display .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook
    Dim SignatureFilePath As String
    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"
    SignatureFilePath = "Office.htm"
    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall   // hangs here
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")
    RangetoHTML = "<BODY style=  color:black;font-size:11.0pt;font-weight:400;font-family:Consolas,monospace>Dear Chetan<p>Please find details<p> </BODY>" & RangetoHTML & "<br><br>" & GetSignature(SignatureFilePath)
    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False
     Debug.Print
    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function

Function GetSignature(fPath As String) As String
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim TSet As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set TSet = fso.GetFile(fPath).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    GetSignature = TSet.readall
    TSet.Close
End Function
```

Comment: This is not [vbscript], nor is it [macros].  This is [vba] so I will update your tags.

Comment: Would it suffice to simply *copy* the range directly in to the outlook email body?

Comment: Alternatively copy the sheet to a new workbook and email the worksheet as attachment?

Answer (score 0):

This will copy & paste the selection from Excel to the Outlook email body, preserving your default signature (if there is one). If you need to add some other signature from file location, you'd need some additional magic.

```
With OutMail
    .To = "xxxxx@xxxxx.com"
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Report" & Format(Now, "dd-MM-yyyy")
    .Display   'or use .Display .Send
    Dim wdDoc As Object     '## Word.Document
    Dim wdRange As Object   '## Word.Range
    Set wdDoc = OutMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
    Set wdRange = wdDoc.Range(0, 0)
    wdRange.InsertAfter vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    'Copy the range in-place
    rng.Copy
    wdRange.Paste
End With
```

Alternatively, copy the data to a new worksheet and send as attachment:

```
Sub SendAsAttachment()
Dim rng As Range
Dim newWB As Workbook
Dim newWS As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Sub
On Error GoTo 0

Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
With newWB
    Set newWS = .Sheets(1)
    newWS.Name = rng.Parent.Name
    rng.Copy newWS.Range("A1")
    Do While .Worksheets.Count > 1
        .Worksheets(.Count).Delete
    Loop
    .SendMail "david.zemens@jdpa.com", "subject", False
    .Close False
End With
End Sub
```

The latter method does not include signature line in the email, though.

Comment: the first method is what I want ,but it copies all the cell ,I want only the one I selected.

Comment: you set your rng variable to ALL visible cells in the Selection. just change that so it's like: `Set rng = Selection.Cells(1)`. This will take only the first cell in whatever is selected.